# Create directory and copy file in roofs in Yocto

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I am trying to create a meta layer for my application. For testing purposes, I would like to have the Image pre-built with a sample video file. I have seen this answered, but it seems that all the answers I find are deprecated.
I am running Yocto Kirkstone.

So, my meta-layer looks like this : video-image.bb

```
SUMMARY = "Adds usb-uvc capabilities, h264 encoding"
IMAGE_INSTALL = "packagegroup-core-boot ${CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL}"
IMAGE_LINGUAS = " "
LICENSE = "MIT"

inherit core-image

# Set rootfs to 1 GB by default
IMAGE_OVERHEAD_FACTOR ?= "1.0"
IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE ?= "1003520"
#IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE:append = "${@bb.utils.contains("DISTRO_FEATURES", "systemd", " + 4096", "", d)}"

inherit extrausers
# Change root password (note the capital -P)
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " \
    usermod -p '\$6\$11223344\$N9q7Gt5eJJb54sBuR/.7ih8w/OeBBQ8D38FmefDKuTMVM5RbnR07FQayQQWSntbXw/DPpuS781UWLHDTY1lhr1' root; \
"

MY_FILES = "/home/antoine/Downloads/qb_helmet_sample.mp4"

FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}/movies"
FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}/movies/${MY_FILES}"

do_install(){
    install -d ${D}${datadir}/movies
    install -m 0644 ${MY_FILES} ${D}${datadir}/movies/
}
```

When I run bitbake video-image, the image is created and I can see the effect of my layer such as the modified root password, but the directory and files are not there. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you are using Kirkstone, that means that `FILES_${PN}` is not valid syntax anymore. Use `FILES:${PN}` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I edited it, but is does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: In the build folder of the recipe there should be a folder called `temp`, something like `build/tmp/work/$ARCH/video-image/$VERSION/temp`. This folder has a file called `run.do_install`. Does this file have a line installing your file? (It's basically a shell script, generated from the recipe's do_install step)

Comment: The seems to be no run.do_install file in the content of the directory! but I don't have any error or warning generated by bitbake...

Comment: Ahhhaaaa, of course. The `core-image` class has `do_install[noexec] = "1"` inside it. If you add `do_install[noexec] = "0"` to your recipe, there could be something interesting happening. (Though I recommend this only as a test. You might want to create your own recipe for the video, without inheriting `core-image`, and add your recipe to the list of installed packages in the image.)

Comment: Makes sense, but now my image file is not being generated! I have nothing to flash to my sd card. It again seems to fail quietly with no error message. I have removed the inherit core-image and all the other stuff except the part concerning the file.

Comment: OK it turns out I had a bad understanding of recipes/layers. I had to move the file copying into its own recipie within my video-image layer and add it to my local.conf file. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I was sleeping. Happy to hear you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`video-image` inherits `core-image` which itself `inherit`s `image`.

To understand what you did, you need to understand that `recipe` has 2 types:

- Package
- Image

A package recipe provides a final package that can be one of the following types:

- `deb`
- `rpm`
- `ipk`

This is controlled via the `PACKAGE_CLASSES` variable that you can find in your `local.conf` file.

So, in order to create a package, a list of `tasks` are executed by `bitbake` on a given recipe `.bb` file, it is like cooking a recipe:

1. `do_fetch`: Download what is in `SRC_URI` into `DL_DIR` (aka `downloads`)
2. `do_unpack`: Upacks what is in `DL_DIR` into `WORKDIR` of the recipe
3. `do_patch`: Apply some patches if `.patch` files found in `SRC_URI`
4. `do_configure`: Do some configuration before compilation
5. `do_compile`: The compilation process
6. `do_install`: This install files to `D` which is `WORKDIR/image` that specifies what should be go into the final package
7. `do_package`: Do create `package` and `package-split` folders for all packages to create of the recipe based on the `FILES` variable
8. `do_package_write_<type>`: Create the final packages, type is one of `deb` `rpm` `ipk`

Also there are some inter tasks like `do_populate_sysroot` and `do_prepare_recipe_sysroot`, `do_package_qa`, ... But it is not important right now.

When dealing with `Image` recipes, there in no task of the previous list.

Image recipes are just a collection of `Package` recipes that `Bitbake` will use to create the final `rootfs`, hince it has other tasks like:

- `do_rootfs`
- `do_image_<type>` type can be one of `IMAGE_FSTYPES` (Example: `ext4`, ..)
- `do_image_complete`

So, in order to add something to an image, it means that you need to add a `Package` recipe to the list that the `Image` recipe uses which is `IMAGE_INSTALL`.

In your case:

1. Create a recipe `.bb` to install your video files

```
meta-custom
   | recipes-videos
       | videos
          | video-recipe_0.1.bb
          | files
             | qb_helmet_sample.mp4
```

- `video-recipe_0.1.bb`

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

MY_FILES = "qb_helmet_sample.mp4"

SRC_URI = "file://${MY_FILES}"

do_install(){
    install -d ${D}${datadir}/movies
    install -m 0644 ${MY_FILES} ${D}${datadir}/movies/
}

FILES:${PN} += "${datadir}/movies/*"
```

2. Add your new recipe to your image:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " video-recipe"
```

**IMPORTANT**

- Never ever ever use absolute paths in your Yocto metadata (layers, recipes, conf, ...)